# Reading data from a scale using serial in Python

Tags: python, serial-port, readline

I use [this scale](https://www.profishop.at/ohaus-ranger-count-3000-zaehlwaage-rc31p1502-30031782?number=OH-566&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIz_uf9LOZ_AIVl-53Ch0VvgHWEAQYASABEgL8Z_D_BwE). It is connected to my RevPi via RS232-USB cable.

This is the python code:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
     port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
     baudrate = 9600,
     parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
     stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
     bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
)

while 1:
    x=ser.readline()
    print(x)
    time.sleep(1)
```

The output with no weight on the scale looks like this:

```
b'          0     g    G \r\n'
```

The code does not work consistantly. Sometimes it would work as expected, meaning that it would display every single change on the scale. On occasions it would only display the inital weight on the scale, but it would not update any weight-changes on the scale.

I don't understand this thematic very well, so I hope somebody can explain this behaviour to me and how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve your exact issue and it is hard to provide a solution without having knowing the hardware connections etc, but I am going to post a better way of doing this with better explanations. Hopefully, this will help you to debug your issue. This is too large for to be added as a comment.

```py
import serial
import time

port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
baudrate = 9600
parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS


# First make sure the port is accessible. This also helps if the port was  
# previously not closed properly.
try:
    temp = serial.Serial(port, baud, bytesize, parity, stopbits)
    
    # Flush both input/output buffer.
    temp.reset_input_buffer()
    temp.reset_output_buffer()

    temp.close()
except:
    print('Unable to open/clean ' + port + ':' + str(baud))
    return

# You are using Ctrl+C to stop the program. Using *with* ensures
# that the serial port is closed when you exit the program.
with serial.Serial(port, baud, bytesize, parity, stopbits) as ser:

    # Start the main loop.
    while True:
        
        # Only read data if there are bytes already waiting in the buffer.
        if ser.in_waiting > 0:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue

        # We got bytes, read them.
        x = ser.readline()
        print(x)
        time.sleep(1)
```